# JSP and GWT , issues with includes

Tags: jsp, gwt

Just getting going with GWT and have struck a problem.

I've got my index JSP with a couple of includes to static header and footer html pages.

```
   <%@ include file="header.html" %>
```

Inside the header and footers are some GWT widgets such as a menu bar, when I run my project in eclipse I get this error

```
10:02:53.970 [ERROR] Remote connection lost
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:304)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelException: Invalid message type CHECK_VERSIONS
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:304)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

If I remove the include, no error.

How do I get around this or is  this not feasible within GWT?

Comment: Do you have any other error before the one you copied here? How many GWT modules (`<script src="….nocache.js">`) do you have on the page?

Comment: Oh, and BTW, DevMode is almost dead nowadays (with only IE still supporting it), so maybe try switching to SuperDevMode?

Comment: SuperDevmode is very slow, unless it changed recently, it takes me 10 minutes to compile my project with 4 workers and 8Gb of ram. for me it is definitely not an alternative to devmode (Unless i decompose my project to subprojects, wich has a consequent cost)

Answer (score 0):

The remote Connextion lost error usually happens when you close the navigator while the server is answering, the server realizes there's no more socket on the other side to answer to and thorows this exception.

It's weired you get this error for an include. Can you show us the code you have in your `header.html` file?

Also notice that since @include is a jsp statement, you're still not in the GWT execution code  when the header is read (the jsp answers with a raw html page that the GWT javascript processes). So you might consider analysing if the error occurs while the jsp is executed or when the GWT module is loading (try commenting out onModuleLoad() content and checking if you still have the error)

Comment: The stacktrace points to `BrowserChannel` which is the part of DevMode responsible for communicating with the GWT Dev Plugin in the browser; so it's actually clear that the error is not in the JSP itself.

Comment: Ah ok, then I must be missing something on how the devmode works. sorry for misleading

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use Vaadin, GWT doesn't seem to be particularly user friendly and a bit of a nightmare too be honest.